# Как разбить строку по буквам в верхнем регистре?

Tags: java, строки

Есть строка (например, `CuOH`), и надо разбить её на массив, разделителем должен являться символ в верхнем регистре (т.е. должен получиться массив `[Cu,O,H]`).

Как это сделать? Я не нашел регулярки, которая позволяет отследить верхний регистр.

Comment: ответ на ваш вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752636/java-split-string-when-an-uppercase-letter-is-found

Answer (score 3):

Если разбивать нужно только по `A-Z`, то с помощью метода `split` и регулярного выражения это можно сделать так:

```
String str = "CuOH";
String[] result = str.split("(?=[A-Z])");
```

Строка разбивается по пустому месту, за которым идёт заглавная буква. Так как заглавная буква при этом присутствует только в "заглядывании вперёд", то в разделитель она не попадает и поэтому остаётся в результате.

---

Для всех заглавных букв Unicode ([класс Lu](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt)):

```
String[] result = str.split("(?=\\p{Lu})");
```

---

На базе [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3752700/3432401) и [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3752693/3432401) ответов.